# Why is Safari's img 'onload' event object empty?

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

What I expect to see (output from Chrome):

[image: Chrome]

What Safari gives me:

[image: Safari]

results achieved in a manner similar to the following:

```
var myHandler;
myHandler = function(e) {
  return console.log(e);
};
var image = new Image()
image.onload = myHandler
image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png"
```

Is there a way to get the expected event object in Safari? Or for that matter ensure proper event object in a browser agnostic manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties are still there, but they are supplied by the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), which Safari's console is collapsing under the `__proto__` property.

A quick test shows that Chrome sets the property on the event object itself, but Safari and Firefox rely on the prototype chain.

```
var myHandler;
myHandler = function(e) {
  return console.log(e.hasOwnProperty("bubbles"));//true in Chrome, false in Safari and Firefox.
};
var image = new Image();
image.onload = myHandler;
image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png";
```

**Note:**

Some of the properties in the `__proto__` are shown as `undefined` in the console, even though actually accessing these properties yields the correct values. I believe Safari is internally using a getter function for these properties.

Comment: Yes but all the relevant information is undefined:

`currentTarget: undefined
defaultPrevented: undefined
eventPhase: undefined
initEvent: function initEvent() {
preventDefault: function preventDefault() {
returnValue: undefined
srcElement: undefined
stopImmediatePropagation: function stopImmediatePropagation() {
stopPropagation: function stopPropagation() {
target: undefined
timeStamp: undefined
type: undefined`

Making it 'empty' as far as my needs.

Comment: @cheshirecatalyst I'm guessing Safari is using some internal getter function. Actually accessing the properties like `bubbles` and `eventPhase` returns the correct value (not `undefined`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. now if only it was consistent, target is null in chrome, have to use the path object, which doesn't exist in safari....sigh ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure that your document is ready? You should have a check for it somewhere using something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: Yes, the document is loaded, everything else is working perfectly.